# How to make the TileMap/TileSet emit a collision signal when my player hits the ground in Godot 4 or higher

Tags: signals, collision-detection, godot4, sktilemapnode, tilesets

In Godot 4, using C#, I'm having difficulty getting a signal for a collision.  I'm using a TileMap/TileSet to create a floor and I added the Physics Layer component. My Player does NOT fall through the floor, my Player hits the floor and stops. So obviously collision is turned on and working perfectly.

However, in the inspector, when you click on the NODE tab, you can see the signals for each node in the tree that you select. I have my Player (RigidBody2D) node selected and I'm trying to get the function _onBodyEntered(Node body) to be called when my player collides with the floor. But no matter what, the TileMap/TileSet will NOT emit this signal.

I just want a solution for how I can guarantee my player is ON THE FLOOR is all I want. I don't need to solve this particular problem if there is an easier way to verify your player is on the floor. But it would be nice to know when my player collides with my TileMap for other parts of the game.

Please DO NOT tell me to read the documentation. I have. Multiple times. It's lacking.

I have made sure the Player is in Layer 1 and my TileMap/TileSet is Layer 2.  I have set BOTH of their MASKS to both 1 and 2.

I have double checked and re-made my TileSet multiple times to make sure I did create the tiles properly with the Collision Paint Physics Layer 0 thing. Not sure why it's called Layer 0 though.  But my tiles DEFINITELY have the collision turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the player isn't falling through the floor indicates that the collision is working properly.

If you want to [detect the collision](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html#character-collision-response) in a `CharacterBody2D`, you need to do so in the `_physics_process`. Specifically, you need to do it in the code that is moving the character (e.g. `move_and_slide` or `move_and_collide`).
Alternatively, if you just want to know that the player is on the ground, use the [`is_on_floor()` function](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_characterbody2d.html#class-characterbody2d-method-is-on-floor).

---

Here's the template code for a `CharacterBody2D` assuming you have `Motion Mode` set to `Grounded` (default).

```
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 300.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")


func _physics_process(delta):
    # Add the gravity.
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    # Handle Jump.
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY

    # Get the input direction and handle the movement/deceleration.
    # As good practice, you should replace UI actions with custom gameplay actions.
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    if direction:
        velocity.x = direction * SPEED
    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)

    move_and_slide()
```

You can modify that last line (`move_and_slide()`) in a couple of ways:

1. Use the boolean result (`true` if a collision occured) for determining whether or not a collision occurred.
2. Switch to `move_and_collide()` and capture the result with is a `KinematicCollision2D`. Use that for handling the collision.